# Is there any way to determine an Akka actor implementation from an ActorRef?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is there any way of determining what is the implementing class behind an Actor based on an `ActorRef`?

I've tried printing `myActor.getClass.getName` but that returns "LocalActorRef". What I want to know is the Class that was specified in the actors Props object at actor creation. Is this possible at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to tell from an `ActorRef` what sort of actor it represents.